# C#, Kerberos - Domain.GetDomain - TGS making use of RC4

Tags: c#, encryption, aes, kerberos

I am writing an application related to AD in C#.

When I execute the following,

```
DirectoryContext context = new DirectoryContext(DirectoryContextType.Domain, "Domain.com");
Domain domain = Domain.GetDomain(context);
```

the Kerberos service ticket log on the domain controller shows the 'Ticket Encryption' type as 0x17 i.e, RC4. The domain and forest functional levels are at Windows Server 2012.

I used WireShark to get some details. The TGS request packet shows AES256,AES128,RC4,DES as the supported encryption types.
The TGS reply packet shows that the encryption type for the ticket is RC4.

If I set a group policy to restrict the usage to AES 128 and 256, the reply will be in AES 256.

My question: If the request packet shows that it supports AES 256, shouldn't the reply be in the same, i.e, the most secure encryption?
Is it a known issue or am I missing something?

PS If it makes any difference, I tried this application with .net Framework 4.0, 4.5, 4.6 in project settings. RC4 was used in all those.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Could be that it chooses compatibility over security for tickets.

Answer (score 1):

The reply for the TGS will have the most secure encryption type specified in the shared secret (the domain controller knows the encryption types it added to the keytab for the service/server).